# bash でJSON の値が特定の値であるかチェックしたい

Tags: bash, jq

APIの JSON レスポンスが特定の値であることをバリデーションするシェルスクリプトを書いているところなのですが不思議な現象に遭遇しました

curl の結果の代用として echo で生成した JSON レスポンスに対して
キー x の中身が "x" という文字列
キー y の中身が "y" という文字列
キー z の中身が "z" という文字列
であることをチェックするテストスクリプトを以下のように書きました

```
X=$(echo '{"x":"x","y":"y","z":"z"}' | jq -r '.x,.y,.z')
Y=$(echo 'x y z')
echo $X
echo $Y
if [ "$X" != "$Y" ]; then echo 'failed'; exit; fi
```

これを動かしたところ

```
x y z
x y z
failed
```

という結果になったのです

比較の直前でデバッグ出力してみると全く同じ出力にもかかわらず結果が failed (文字列不一致の分岐) になります

何故なのでしょうか

Comment: "特定の値" が何を指しているのかやや分かりづらいように感じます。一つと言ったら通常は `x`, `y`, `z` の内どれかとも受け取れるし、`$Y = 'x y z'` の中身を値と見るのかで印象が違います。

Comment: `$Y` の様にスペース区切りで出力する場合は `X=$(echo '{"x":"x","y":"y","z":"z"}' | jq -r 'join(" ")')` としても良いかと思います。

Comment: 質問用のサンプルなので１列のJSONでしたが、実際はもっと多段のJSONが帰ってきて、中の全てがチェック対象ではないのです。全て対象なら JSON 文字列ごと比較すれば済むのですが特定のキーだけを比較したいです

Comment: 例えば x と z だけを比較する場合は `echo '{"x":"x","y":"y","z":"z"}' | jq -r '[.x, .z]|join(" ")'` とします。

Comment: jq のステートメントにパイプみたいなのがあるんですね！うまく行きました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

クォートを入れ、

```
echo "$X"
echo "$Y"
```

にして試してみてください。

jq の出力した `$X` はスペース区切り 1 行の文字列ではなく、改行区切り 3 行の文字列です。`echo $X` だと `echo` に 3 つの引数が与えられたとみなされてそれらがスペース区切りで出力されますが、`echo "$X"` だと 1 つの引数が与えられるだけで、`$X` の中身がそのまま出力されます。

スペース区切り 1 行の文字列として出力するには、`jq` の `join` を使うと良さそうです。ただし値にスペースが含まれる場合それが区別できなくなるので気をつけてください。

```
echo '{"x":"x","y":"y","z":"z"}' | jq -r '[.x,.y,.z]|join(" ")'
```

Comment: $X と "$X" で echo の結果が変わるのですね。勉強になりました

Answer (score 1):

`$X` の方は**3つの要素**を抜き出している一方、

```
$ echo '{"x":"x","y":"y","z":"z"}' | jq -r '.x,.y,.z'
x
y
z
```

`$Y = 'x y z'` はシングルクォーテーションを使用しているので3つの要素ではなく、**ひと塊の文字列**とみなされて比較結果が意図した通りになっていないのだと思います。

Comment: 3つの要素を比較したいのですが 値を別の変数に取得して値の数だけ比較というのが冗長になりそうだったので、あえて 「ひと塊の文字列」にして比較しようと思ってました